# Mapping the world on ggplot2

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

I've been trying to plot a map of the world on ggplot2. I followed the threads of emails: [ggplot map with l](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558040/ggplot-map-with-l) but I do run into the same error message and I don't understand the author comments on how to fix it.

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(maptools)
library(sp)
gpclibPermit()

world.map <- readOGR(dsn="data", layer="TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3")
world.ggmap <- fortify(world.map, region = "NAME")

> world.ggmap <- fortify(world.map, region = "NAME")
Error in nchar(ID) : invalid multibyte string 1
```

Comment: What is your `sessionInfo()`? MAke sure you have the latest R and packages. Do you still get this error?

Comment: have you studied [this question on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558040/ggplot-map-with-l)

Answer (score 6):

So, I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles), more or less, to create this world map:

[image: ggplot2 world]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cshapes)
world <- cshp(date=as.Date("2008-1-1"))
world.points <- fortify(world, region='COWCODE')
p <- ggplot(world.points, aes(long,lat,group=group)) + geom_polygon()
p
```

It looks like it takes some more work to combine this with data, e.g. for a thematic map, but the post above goes through this in detail.

Not sure if you still need an answer to this, but I hope it's helpful to someone in any case.

Comment: Helpful at least for anyone except inhabitants of Greenland ;)