# How can I draw something in the background of a ggplot?

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

I'm working on making shot charts for basketball. I need to figure out how to actually draw the outline of a basketball court in the background. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look at `annotate_raster` or similar.

Comment: Cool question. You could do something with `+ geom_path(data=<basketball_court_specs>)`, if you know how a basket ball court is laid out. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805895/mapping-the-world-on-ggplot2 for ideas (replace `geom_polygon` with `geom_path`).

Comment: @EvanZamir: you should post that last image with the code in an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

The following code was used to get this image:

```
    ggplot(shots, aes(X,Y)) + stat_binhex(binwidth=c(3,3)) + 
    geom_point(size=3, alpha=0.5, aes(color=RESULT), position="jitter") + 
    coord_equal() + theme_grey() + opts(title="Golden State Warriors 2012 Shot Chart") + 
    geom_path(data=ft_line, aes(x,y), colour="white", size=2) + 
    geom_path(data=court, aes(x,y), colour="white", size=2)
```

The data in the geom_path commands contains the (x,y) coords for the white court diagram.